# Make minecraft generate regions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way to make Minecraft to generate regions other than teleporting there?

I want to make a custom world, but I'm looking for a particular set of biomes and area. I've tried creating worlds, tp-ing around, checking out the maps and the deleting them, but it's a time consuming process.

It'd be great if there was a command I could give to make Minecraft generate a region automatically and then I could just use JourneyMap's automap feature to check them out. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you're just looking for a region setup you could preview your seeds using [Mineatlas](http://mineatlas.com/) or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite easy. It's nothing related to commands.

- New world
- Advanced world options
- World Type: Customized
- Click customize
- Biomes: Drag to which one you like, river, ocean, deep ocean, snow plains, whatever you want.
- Drag up biome size, so you'll the biome will be bigger.
- Magic!! (not really)

---

Optional (if you want the world to be flatter)

- Last but second page.
- Height stretch
- Increase it from 12 to 14 or so. It will be flatter.

Comment: I think OP was looking for a solution for an existing world, not a new one.